# Download zip file from remote HTTPS host using netcat

Tags: command-line, download, netcat

I'm trying to download a zip file from : https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip (no curl and no WGET). I want to do that by netcat i used this command :

```
echo -e "GET
https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: download.sysinternals.com\r\n\r\n" | nc download.sysinternals.com 80 > q.zip
```

The file is written on the HDD but when I try to open it its corrupted.

Comment: So you're trying to download a Windows tool onto a Linux system, from a remote server over HTTPS, without making use of the `curl` & `wget` tools which are written specifically to work with the HTTP protocol. I'm wondering why this whole thing is so convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as far as I know, `netcat` cannot use HTTPS, but in your code you were connecting to port 80, which means HTTP, not HTTPS.

After the `GET` you should add the relative address, not the full one.

Something like this will work:

```
echo -e "GET /files/ProcessExplorer.zip HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: download.sysinternals.com\r\n\r\n" | nc download.sysinternals.com 80 > q.temp
```

It will not close when the transfer is finished, you'll have to close it manually.

At this point the `q.temp` file have also the HTTP header included, you'll have to remove it. You can check the line number where the binary content starts with:

```
nl q.temp | less
```

In this case the binary content starts at line 16, so you can remove the header with:

```
tail -n +16 q.temp > q.zip
```

And there you have your zip file!

Comment: It just works by pure chance, but it works. Congrats on your answer.

Comment: Cool!  Mine deleted, yours upvoted.